# Is it possible to add an user interface to a Selenium based application in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, user-interface, whatsapp, user-experience

Hi there fellow programmers.

I've been learning Python for a few months and I've built some automation scripts for WhatsApp Web tasks, like sending messages and media, extracting contacts from groups, etc.

I did some research here on StackOverFlow, on YouTube and Google, but couldn't find any specific resources on how to build an User Interface in Python to manage Selenium tasks.

The question is if it's possible to join my Selenium scripts into a Software where I can control and choose functionalities via an User Interface.

I know there are libraries for building User Interfaces like Tkinker and PySimpleGui, but I think it would be good for me and anyone experiencing the same issue if an experienced programmer just pointed an effective path to solve this issue.

My goal is to make possible for an average user, with no programming background, to enjoy the easiness of doing repetitive tasks on WhatsApp Web by using all the power that Python and Selenium has to offer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tkinter and buttons and textfield control specific routines of a selenium application.

Pygame could also work.

Comment: Thanks, man. I'll do some research about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to make a nice and user-friendly GUI for your Selenium scripts!

I'm using Python with Selenium and PySimpleGUI (the tkinter version). I like PySimpleGUI because it makes it possible to have a much shorter, easily readable code (no extensive boilerplates needed): it is possible to use a lot of defaults and only specify those variables that really need to be set or changed. On PySimpleGUI's GitHub, there are quite many useful examples to get you started as well as to learn some more advanced tricks.

Where PySimpleGUI didn't allow to access some specific features (which was just a couple of times for our tasks, e.g., concerning the WM attributes), we were able to access the underlying tkinter structures.